# ¿Cómo representar una grid de preguntas en un marco de datos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, diccionarios

Tengo json que representa una cuadrícula de preguntas y respuestas de los formularios de Google y me gustaria extraerlo en una dataframe:

```
{'question': 'To what extent are the following factors considerations in your choice of flight? ', 'answers': [None, 7, [[514996986, [['Very important consideration'], ['Important consideration'], ['Neutral'], ['Not an important consideration'], ['Do not consider']], 0, ['The airline/company you fly with'], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [1]], [396483948, [['Very important consideration'], ['Important consideration'], ['Neutral'], ['Not an important consideration'], ['Do not consider']], 0, ['The departure airport'], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [1]], [971070641, [['Very important consideration'], ['Important consideration'], ['Neutral'], ['Not an important consideration'], ['Do not consider']], 0, ['Duration of flight/route'], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [1]], [1685960105, [['Very important consideration'], ['Important consideration'], ['Neutral'], ['Not an important consideration'], ['Do not consider']], 0, ['Price'], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [1]], [231217486, [['Very important consideration'], ['Important consideration'], ['Neutral'], ['Not an important consideration'], ['Do not consider']], 0, ['Baggage policy'], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [1]], [940990935, [['Very important consideration'], ['Important consideration'], ['Neutral'], ['Not an important consideration'], ['Do not consider']], 0, ['Environmental impacts'], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [1]]]]}
```

Representa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaria ponerlo en una dataframe con

```
QID    Questions    Answer_1    Answer_2    Answer_3    Answer_4    Answer_5                                                                        
0      To what extent are the following factors considerations in your choice of flight?    'Very important consideration'    'Important consideration'    'Neutral'    'Not an important consideration'    'Do not consider'
0_S01  'The airline/company you fly with'
0_S02  'The departure airport'
0_S03  'Duration of flight/route'
0_S04  'Baggage policy'
...
```

Hasta hoy intenté crear nombres de columna
:

```
>>> li = ['Answer{i}' for i in range(0,len(l))]
>>> columns = ['QID', 'Questions', itertools.chain.from_iterable(li)]
>>> pd.DataFrame(columns)
                                                0
0                                             QID
1                                       Questions
2  <itertools.chain object at 0x000001E2F41DC188>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Cómo representar una grid de preguntas en un marco de datos?

De los datos en cuestión hay que sacar los elementos necesarios...

### Consiguiendo preguntas:

Analizando el diccionario que contiene toda la información

```
data = {'question': 'To what extent are the following factors considerations in your choice of flight? ', 'answers': [None, 7, [[514996986, [['Very important consideration'], ['Important consideration'], ['Neutral'], ['Not an important consideration'], ['Do not consider']], 0, ['The airline/company you fly with'], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [1]], [396483948, [['Very important consideration'], ['Important consideration'], ['Neutral'], ['Not an important consideration'], ['Do not consider']], 0, ['The departure airport'], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [1]], [971070641, [['Very important consideration'], ['Important consideration'], ['Neutral'], ['Not an important consideration'], ['Do not consider']], 0, ['Duration of flight/route'], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [1]], [1685960105, [['Very important consideration'], ['Important consideration'], ['Neutral'], ['Not an important consideration'], ['Do not consider']], 0, ['Price'], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [1]], [231217486, [['Very important consideration'], ['Important consideration'], ['Neutral'], ['Not an important consideration'], ['Do not consider']], 0, ['Baggage policy'], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [1]], [940990935, [['Very important consideration'], ['Important consideration'], ['Neutral'], ['Not an important consideration'], ['Do not consider']], 0, ['Environmental impacts'], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [1]]]]}
```

Uno se da cuenta de un par de cosas:

- **Las preguntas siguen una frecuencia de aparición en todo el diccionario**

Vamos a empezar descartando el valor de la llave `["question"]`, debido a que ahí no están las preguntas. En la otra llave `["Answers"]` podemos descartar los primeros dos valores de la lista:

```
print(data["answers"][2][0])
```

Con esto visualizamos que tambén podemos descartar el primer y segundo valor de esta lista, ya que el primer valor es un número y el segundo una lista con las **pregunta**. Por otro lado (literalmente), podemos ver que se pueden descartar todos los `None` y otros valores nulos. Con esto obtenemos la primera pregunta:

```
print(data["answers"][2][0][3])
```

muestra:

```
['The airline/company you fly with']
```

Si seguimos analizando a `data` nos daremos cuenta que todas las preguntas está en la cuarta ubicación de una lista contenida en la primera lista de `data` (el tercer elemento). Entonces podemos obtener **todas las preguntas** con una expresión generadora:

```
[data["answers"][2][x][3] for x in range(len(data["answers"][2]))]
```

Pero, nos surge un problema, cada pregunta está contenida en una lista individual. Lo más optimo es usar `reduce()` de `functools`:

```
from functools import reduce

questions = reduce(lambda a,b: a + b,[data["answers"][2][x][3] for x in range(len(data["answers"][2]))])
```

`print(questions)` muestra:

```
['The airline/company you fly with', 'The departure airport', 'Duration of flight/route', 'Price', 'Baggage policy', 'Environmental impacts']
```

### Consiguiendo respuestas:

Aplicar la misma metodología para encontrar las respuestas sería:

1. Más tardado
2. Innecesario
3. Relativamente díficil

Al final de cuentas, **todos las preguntas van a tener las mismas respuestas**. Por lo tanto, no es necesario encontrarlas todas, si no encontrarlas una vez y repetirlas.

Es mucho más fácil manejar todo en una lista, para después montar bien el `DataFrame`.

**Buscando las primeras preguntas:**

Analizando a `data` nuevamente, nos vamos a dar cuenta que la secuencia de indices `[2][0][1]` ubica a una lista con todas las respuestas. Lastimosamente, también está contenidas individualmente en listas. Se puede usar `reduce()` para solucionar esto, pero también hay que multiplicarlas para que hayan respuestas para todas las preguntas. Podemos hacer las dos cosas a la vez:

```
ind_answers = data["answers"][2][0][1]
answers = []
for i in range(len(ind_answers)):
    answers.append(reduce(lambda a,b: a + b,[ind_answers[i] for x in range(len(questions))]))
```

mostraría:

```
[['Very important consideration', 'Very important consideration', 'Very important consideration', 'Very important consideration', 'Very important consideration', 'Very important consideration'], ['Important consideration', 'Important consideration', 'Important consideration', 'Important consideration', 'Important consideration', 'Important consideration'], ['Neutral', 'Neutral', 'Neutral', 'Neutral', 'Neutral', 'Neutral'], ['Not an important consideration', 'Not an important consideration', 'Not an important consideration', 'Not an important consideration', 'Not an important consideration', 'Not an important consideration'], ['Do not consider', 'Do not consider', 'Do not consider', 'Do not consider', 'Do not consider', 'Do not consider']]
```

Antes de seguir hay que parar y analizar que pasó aquí.

**¿Qué acaba de pasar?**

La variable `ind_answers` es la encargada de almacenar la primera ocurrrencía de las preguntas en `data`. En esta expresión: `answers.append(reduce(lambda a,b: a + b,[ind_answers[i] for x in range(len(questions))]))` se está añadiendo la lista reducida que da como resultado la multiplicación de los valores de `ind_answers`. Por lo tanto se obtienen, cinco listas con seis respuestas.

### Cargando el `DataFrame`:

La manera más fácil en mi opinión es cargar el `DataFrame` desde un diccionario.

**¿Pero, por qué?**

Al cargar el `DataFrame` desde un diccionario puedes especificar directamente el nombre de las columnas y el contenido de las columnas con una lista. Para hacer esto hay que montar un diccionario con este tipo de estructura:

```
{"Nombre de la columna":[Valores,de,la,columna]}
```

Este diccionario se estaría montando de la siguiente manera:

```
dict_ = {"Questions": questions,"Answer_1":answers[0],"Answer_2":answers[1],"Answer_3":answers[2],"Answer_4":answers[3],"Answer_5":answers[4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_)
```

Si hacemos `print(df)` para ver el resultado, veríamos

```
                          Questions                      Answer_1  ...                        Answer_4         Answer_5
0  The airline/company you fly with  Very important consideration  ...  Not an important consideration  Do not consider
1             The departure airport  Very important consideration  ...  Not an important consideration  Do not consider
2          Duration of flight/route  Very important consideration  ...  Not an important consideration  Do not consider
3                             Price  Very important consideration  ...  Not an important consideration  Do not consider
4                    Baggage policy  Very important consideration  ...  Not an important consideration  Do not consider
5             Environmental impacts  Very important consideration  ...  Not an important consideration  Do not consider

[6 rows x 6 columns]
```

> Me gustaria ponerlo en una dataframe con

```
QID    Questions    Answer_1    Answer_2    Answer_3    Answer_4    Answer_5                                                                        
0      To what extent are the following factors considerations in your choice of flight?    'Very important consideration'    'Important consideration'    'Neutral'    'Not an important consideration'    'Do not consider'
0_S01  'The airline/company you fly with'
0_S02  'The departure airport'
0_S03  'Duration of flight/route'
0_S04  'Baggage policy'
...
```

Usemos los mismo métodos de obtención para las preguntas y respuestas, solo que esta vez vamos a montar el `DataFrame` de diferente manera.

### Obteniendo la información de `data`:

Las preguntas se obtendrían igual, si notas la única diferencia es que esta vez se debe de incluir la pregunta que está en `data["question"]`:

```
questions = reduce(lambda a,b: a + b,[data["answers"][2][x][3] for x in range(len(data["answers"][2]))])
questions.insert(0,data["question"])
```

con `print(questions)` mostraría:

```
['To what extent are the following factors considerations in your choice of flight? ', 'The airline/company you fly with', 'The departure airport', 'Duration of flight/route', 'Price', 'Baggage policy', 'Environmental impacts']
```

Ahora hay que variar la manera de obtener las respuestas, por suerte para bien. Ahora es mucho más fácil:

**¿Como se consiguen los espacios en blanco?**

A la hora de montar el diccionario se deben de usar listas con la **misma longitud**. La solución que le veo a esto es usar un relleno, sea `None` o bien un espacio en blanco `""`.

```
fill = [None for x in range(len(questions) - 1)]
```

Para hacer todo un marcco de preguntas hay que conseguir las pregunta en su primera ocurrencia, luego multplicar entre sí y sumar con `fill` (el relleno):

```
ind_answers = data["answers"][2][0][1]
answers = []
for i in range(len(ind_answers)):
    answers.append(ind_answers[i] + fill)
```

Dentro del cilo `for` se pueden hacer ambos procedimientos. Nuestras preguntas quedarían así:

```
[['Very important consideration', None, None, None, None, None, None], ['Important consideration', None, None, None, None, None, None], ['Neutral', None, None, None, None, None, None], ['Not an important consideration', None, None, None, None, None, None], ['Do not consider', None, None, None, None, None, None]]
```

### Montando el diccionario y `DataFrame`:

Bien se puede montar el diccionario de la misma forma, solo que esta vez a la hora de montar el `DataFrame` habría que cambiar la manera en que se indexa verticalmente este.

```
indexing = ["QID"] + ["0_S0{}".format(i) for i in range(1,len(questions))]
dict_ = {"Questions":questions,"Answer_1":answers[0],"Answer_2":answers[1],"Answer_3":answers[2],"Answer_4":answers[3],"Answer_5":answers[4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_,index = indexing)
```

Redactando el final de esta respuesta, me dí cuenta que se ve mejor con los espacios en blanco en vez de los `None`. Entonces hice este cambio:

```
fill = ["" for x in range(len(questions) - 1)]
```

Por lo tanto, con `print(df)` se vería esto:

```
                                               Questions  ...         Answer_5
QID    To what extent are the following factors consi...  ...  Do not consider
0_S01                   The airline/company you fly with  ...
0_S02                              The departure airport  ...
0_S03                           Duration of flight/route  ...
0_S04                                              Price  ...
0_S05                                     Baggage policy  ...
0_S06                              Environmental impacts  ...

[7 rows x 6 columns]
```

Muy probablemente se vea diferente si estás usando un cuaderno, u otra herramienta de visualización.

Espero te haya servido de algo, saludos.