# Comprobar si hay grid de preguntas en un diccionario

Tags: python, python-3.x, diccionarios

Tengo un [archivo pickle que representa preguntas y respuestas](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15boZG27t_DL8SEMn-ObyRMqKE3bCFR1I/view?usp=sharing) en un formato diccionario y me gustaria saber donde estan los que estan grid de preguntas como la siguiente para puestarlas en un csv como gcoronel99 lo hicé [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/375097/2633):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La estructura de este ejemplo esta como la siguente:

```
{'question': 'To what extent are the following factors considerations in your choice of flight? ',
   'answers': [None,
    7,
    [[514996986,
      [['Very important consideration'],
       ['Important consideration'],
       ['Neutral'],
       ['Not an important consideration'],
       ['Do not consider']],
      0,
      ['The airline/company you fly with'],
      None,
      None,
      None,
      None,
      None,
      None,
      None,
      [1]],
     [396483948,
      [['Very important consideration'],
       ['Important consideration'],
       ['Neutral'],
       ['Not an important consideration'],
       ['Do not consider']],
      0,
      ['The departure airport'],
      None,
      None,
      None,
      None,
      None,
      None,
      None,
      [1]],
     [971070641,
      [['Very important consideration'],
       ['Important consideration'],
       ['Neutral'],
       ['Not an important consideration'],
       ['Do not consider']],
      0,
      ['Duration of flight/route'],
      None,
      None,
      None,
      None,
      None,
      None,
      None,
      [1]],
     [1685960105,
      [['Very important consideration'],
       ['Important consideration'],
       ['Neutral'],
       ['Not an important consideration'],
       ['Do not consider']],
      0,
      ['Price'],
      None,
      None,
      None,
      None,
      None,
      None,
      None,
      [1]],
     [231217486,
      [['Very important consideration'],
       ['Important consideration'],
       ['Neutral'],
       ['Not an important consideration'],
       ['Do not consider']],
      0,
      ['Baggage policy'],
      None,
      None,
      None,
      None,
      None,
      None,
      None,
      [1]],
     [940990935,
      [['Very important consideration'],
       ['Important consideration'],
       ['Neutral'],
       ['Not an important consideration'],
       ['Do not consider']],
      0,
      ['Environmental impacts'],
      None,
      None,
      None,
      None,
      None,
      None,
      None,
      [1]]]]}
```

Pero para los demas (si ya existen) pueden variar en funcion de la lineas o columnas. En el caso general pienso que una grid se reconoce cuando hay, en las `answers` multiples tabulas de tabulas de tabulas.

Entonces intenté saber si funciona a lo menos con el ejemplo arriba:

```
import pickle

dic = pd.read_pickle(r'Python/interns.p')

def isGrid(qa):
    d_answers = qa['answers']
#     print("qa['question']: ", qa['question'])
    if qa['question'] == 'To what extent are the following factors considerations in your choice of flight?':
        try:
            print("qa['question']: ", qa['question'])
            answers = d_answers[2]
            if len(answers)>1:
                print(True)
                return True
        except TypeError:
            print("truc")
    
for qa_set in dic:
    for qa in qa_set:
        bool_grid = isGrid(qa)
```

Pero obtengo:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1062-6d260b7f25bc> in <module>
     18 for qa_set in dic:
     19     for qa in qa_set:
---> 20         bool_grid = isGrid(qa)
     21 
     22 # isGrid(qa)

<ipython-input-1062-6d260b7f25bc> in isGrid(qa)
      4 
      5 def isGrid(qa):
----> 6     d_answers = qa['answers']
      7 #     print("qa['question']: ", qa['question'])
      8     if qa['question'] == 'To what extent are the following factors considerations in your choice of flight?':

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ¿Por que se obtiene el error?

Primero revisemos que implica iterar sobre un diccionario:

```
for key in dic:
    print(key)
```

Se pensaría que este ciclo imprimiría cada par ordenado del diccionario, algo así:

```
question: To what extent are the following factors considerations in your choice of flight?
answers: [None, 7, [[514996986, [['Very important consideration'], ['Important consideration'], ['Neutral'], ['Not an important consideration'], ['Do not consider']], 0, ['The airline/company you fly with'], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [1]], [396483948, [['Very important consideration'], ['Important consideration'], ['Neutral'], ['Not an important consideration'], ['Do not consider']], 0, ['The departure airport'], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [1]], [971070641, [['Very important consideration'], ['Important consideration'], ['Neutral'], ['Not an important consideration'], ['Do not consider']], 0, ['Duration of flight/route'], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [1]], [1685960105, [['Very important consideration'], ['Important consideration'], ['Neutral'], ['Not an important consideration'], ['Do not consider']], 0, ['Price'], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [1]], [231217486, [['Very important consideration'], ['Important consideration'], ['Neutral'], ['Not an important consideration'], ['Do not consider']], 0, ['Baggage policy'], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [1]], [940990935, [['Very important consideration'], ['Important consideration'], ['Neutral'], ['Not an important consideration'], ['Do not consider']], 0, ['Environmental impacts'], None, None, None, None, None, None, None, [1]]]]
```

**¿Qué pasa realmente?**

Realmente solo imprime los valores de las llaves como los strings que son:

```
question
answers
```

Entonces el ciclo anidado de

```
for qa_set in dic:
    for qa in qa_set:
        bool_grid = isGrid(qa)
```

Esta ejecutando la función, con cada letra de ambas palabras. Esto se puede comparar imprimiendo el valor de `qa` por pantalla:

```
for qa_set in dic:
    for qa in qa_set:
        print(qa)
```

muestra

```
q
u
e
s
t
i
o
n
a
n
s
w
e
r
s
```

Entonces el error en la linea `d_answers = qa['answers']` tiene sentido ahora. La letra individual es un string y se está intentando acceder a una llave como si fuera un diccionario. En otras plabras lo ocurre es esto:

```
d_answers = "q"['answers']
```

Por esto mismo ocurre el error

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

los string no tiene llaves, **solo indices**. El primer error que obtienes se da debido al segundo.

### ¿Realmente la función `isGrid()` funciona?

La respuesta es que no, en el condicional

```
if qa['question'] == 'To what extent are the following factors considerations in your choice of flight?':
```

Estás evaluando si esa llave es igual a ese string, si te fijas en el diccionario `dic` el valor de la llave `["question"]` es este string que evaluas, pero con un espacio al final. Para no modificar los datos la solución sería esta:

```
if qa['question'].strip() == 'To what extent are the following factors considerations in your choice of flight?':
```

Debido a que el método `.strip()` elimina los espacios al final y principio de una cadena.

### ¿Es necesario ejecutar la función con cada par ordenado de `dic`?

A mi punto de vista no, debido a que en la función se opera con ambos pares ordenados del diccionario. Solo basta con usar como parámetro de la función a `dic`.

**La función:**

```
def isGrid(qa):
    d_answers = qa['answers']
    if qa['question'].strip() == 'To what extent are the following factors considerations in your choice of flight?':
        try:
            print("qa['question']: ", qa['question'])
            answers = d_answers[2]
            if len(answers) > 1:
                print(True)
                return True
        except TypeError:
            print("truc")
```

**Usando a `dic` como parámetro:**

```
isGrid(dic)
```

devolvería

```
qa['question']:  To what extent are the following factors considerations in your choice of flight?
True
```

Claramente tendrás tus razones para realizar esa iteración, **no sé que tienes en el picke**. Sin embargo, al menos ya sabes por que se produce tu error.