# ¿Cómo actualizar una dataframe con otra?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Tengo [una dataframe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uni59GR0wxsjpLtLZkfJ0Hk6sL-aYAcd/view?usp=sharing) con preguntas numeradas (`QID`), pero esos números ya no significaban nada, [otro con los números correctos](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D-WhqHn4mPPSXbBDdk-cB7bdllLcK8W-/view?usp=sharing). Me gustaría actualizar el ultima con los numeros correctos. Y una vez encontrada esta coincidencia, añadimos todas las columnas que faltan de df_original a df.

`df` es `df_original` con una differencia: cambio unas pocas líneas que en realidad fue títulos de QuestionGrid, con nuevas líneas que también representan las respuestas de QuestionGrid. Pueden ver como lo hice en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/375476/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-reemplazar-una-l%C3%ADnea-con-varias-otras-l%C3%ADneas-en-una-dataframe). Así que debería haber más lineas en `df` que en `df_original`.

Aqui es un estracto de la dataframe original:

```
 >>> df_original.iloc[18:25,:10]
    QID     URL     Questions   Answers     Section     QType   Theme   Topics  Answer0     Answer1
18  17  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MYSjxAMCXMXB0...   What is you preference of room/suites with bal...   ['Preferred', 'Not preferred']  Consumer Intentions     Multiple Choice     Hotel ABC   ['prefer', 'room', 'suit', 'balconi']   Preferred   Not preferred
19  18  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MYSjxAMCXMXB0...   How do you want your guestroom to look like?    ['Contemporary style guestrooms', 'Traditional...   Consumer Intentions     Multiple Choice     Hotel ABC   ['want', 'guestroom', 'look', 'like']   Contemporary style guestrooms   NaN
20  19  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MYSjxAMCXMXB0...   How do you want to know about our recent offer...   ['Personalized emails', 'Text messages', 'Web ...   Media Consumption   Multiple Choice     Hotel ABC   ['want', 'know', 'recent', 'offer']     Personalized emails     Text messages
21  20  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MYSjxAMCXMXB0...   What are new offers you are most interested in?     ['Not Interested', 'Somewhat Interested', 'Int...   Media Consumption   Multiple Choice     Hotel ABC   ['offer', 'interest']   Not Interested  Somewhat Interested
22  21  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MYSjxAMCXMXB0...   How often do you want to hear on these offerings?   ['Weekly', 'Bi-Weekly', 'Monthly', 'Quarterly']     Media Consumption   Multiple Choice     Hotel ABC   ['want', 'hear', 'offer']   Weekly  Bi-Weekly
23  22  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MYSjxAMCXMXB0...   What medium do you prefer for any change / ca...    ['Through calls', 'Through text messages', 'Th...   Media Consumption   Multiple Choice     Hotel ABC   ['medium', 'prefer', 'chang', 'cancel', 'book']     Through calls   Through text messages
24  23  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MYSjxAMCXMXB0...   Gender  ['Male', 'Female', "Others (Don't Wish to Spec...   Name (Optional)     Multiple Choice     Hotel ABC   ['gender']  Male    Female
```

Y aqui es una parte de `df`:

```
 >>>df.iloc[23:30,:10]
        QID     Questions   QType   Answer0     Answer1     Answer2     Answer3     Answer4     Answer5
23      22  How do you want to know about our recent offer...   Multiple Choice     Personalized emails     Text messages   Web Blogs   Paper advertisements    Video advertisements    Advertisements on social media
24      23  What are new offers you are most interested in?     Question Grid   Not Interested  Somewhat Interested     Interested  Highly Interested   Very Highly Interested  NaN
25      23_1    Discount on hotel's room charges    Question Grid   Not Interested  Somewhat Interested     Interested  Highly Interested   Very Highly Interested  NaN
26      23_2    Hotel's reward points (Loyalty program)     Question Grid   Not Interested  Somewhat Interested     Interested  Highly Interested   Very Highly Interested  NaN
27      23_3    Hotel's hygiene policy  Question Grid   Not Interested  Somewhat Interested     Interested  Highly Interested   Very Highly Interested  NaN
28      23_4    Hotel medical services  Question Grid   Not Interested  Somewhat Interested     Interested  Highly Interested   Very Highly Interested  NaN
29      23_5    In-hotel services offerings     Question Grid   Not Interested  Somewhat Interested     Interested  Highly Interested   Very Highly Interested  NaN
```

Y me gustaria:

```
 >>>df.iloc[23:30,:10]
        QID     Questions   QType   Answer0     Answer1     Answer2     Answer3     Answer4     Answer5
24      20    https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MYSjxAMCXMXB0...     What are new offers you are most interested in?     ['Not Interested', 'Somewhat Interested', 'Int...   Media Consumption   Question Grid   Not Interested  Somewhat Interested     Interested  Highly Interested   Very Highly Interested  NaN
25      20_1    https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MYSjxAMCXMXB0...   Discount on hotel's room charges    ['Not Interested', 'Somewhat Interested', 'Int...   Media Consumption    Discount on hotel's room charges   Question Grid   Not Interested  Somewhat Interested     Interested  Highly Interested   Very Highly Interested  NaN
26      20_2    https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MYSjxAMCXMXB0...   Hotel's reward points (Loyalty program)     ['Not Interested', 'Somewhat Interested', 'Int...   Media Consumption    Hotel's reward points (Loyalty program)    Question Grid   Not Interested  Somewhat Interested     Interested  Highly Interested   Very Highly Interested  NaN
27      20_3    https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MYSjxAMCXMXB0...   Hotel's hygiene policy  ['Not Interested', 'Somewhat Interested', 'Int...   Media Consumption     Hotel's hygiene policy    Question Grid   Not Interested  Somewhat Interested     Interested  Highly Interested   Very Highly Interested  NaN
28      23_4    https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MYSjxAMCXMXB0...   Hotel medical services  ['Not Interested', 'Somewhat Interested', 'Int...   Media Consumption    Hotel medical services     Question Grid   Not Interested  Somewhat Interested     Interested  Highly Interested   Very Highly Interested  NaN
29      23_5    https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MYSjxAMCXMXB0...   In-hotel services offerings     ['Not Interested', 'Somewhat Interested', 'Int...   Media Consumption    In-hotel services offerings    Question Grid   Not Interested  Somewhat Interested     Interested  Highly Interested   Very Highly Interested  NaN
```

Hasta hoy intenté:

```
def verify_qid(row, df_original):
    for i, row_original in df_original.iterrows():
        if row_original['Questions'] == row['Questions']:
            row['QID'] = row_original['QID']
            print(type(row_original), row_original)
            for key in row_original.keys() not in row.keys():
                # si la columna ya no existe en row la puestamos
                row[key] = row_original[key]

                

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    qid = row['QID']
    # Verificamos qid con el de df_original 
    verify_qid(row, df_original) # si la pregunta es la misma pero el QID no lo es
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> QID                                                                  0
URL                  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MYSjxAMCXMXB0...
Questions              When do you think your next vacation can start?
Answers              ['In next 3 months', 'In next 6 months', 'In n...
Section                                                            NaN
                                           ...                        
11e                                                                NaN
Sum                                                                  2
Comment              google forum seems broken at points needs to b...
Beyond repair                                                      NaN
Not scrapped well                                                  NaN
Name: 0, Length: 333, dtype: object

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-f7d6a63c90da> in <module>
     13     qid = row['QID']
     14     # Verificamos qid con el de df_original
---> 15     verify_qid(row, df_original) # si la pregunta es la misma pero el QID no lo es
     16 
     17 

<ipython-input-72-f7d6a63c90da> in verify_qid(row, df_original)
      4             row['QID'] = row_original['QID']
      5             print(type(row_original), row_original)
----> 6             for key in row_original.keys() not in row.keys():
      7                 # si la columna ya no existe en row la puestamos
      8                 row[key] = row_original[key]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in __contains__(self, key)
   3898     @Appender(_index_shared_docs["contains"] % _index_doc_kwargs)
   3899     def __contains__(self, key) -> bool:
-> 3900         hash(key)
   3901         try:
   3902             return key in self._engine

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in __hash__(self)
   3905 
   3906     def __hash__(self):
-> 3907         raise TypeError(f"unhashable type: {repr(type(self).__name__)}")
   3908 
   3909     def __setitem__(self, key, value):

TypeError: unhashable type: 'Index'
```

Tambien intenté:

```
for i, row_original in df_original.iterrows():    
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        if row_original['Questions'] == row['Questions']:
            qid = str(row['QID']).split("_")
            # get the sub dataframe where the first part of the QID is the same with qid
            sub_df = df.loc[df['QID'].split("_")[0] == qid[0]] # df['QID'].split("_")[0], to get the qgrid rows
            # for each question in sub_df adapt their qid with row_original qid respecting "_" and provide the row values 
            for sub_row in sub_df.iterrows():
                sub_qid = str(sub_row['QID']).split("_")
                new_qid = str(row['QID'])+"_"+sub_qid[1]
                sub_row['QID'] = new_qid
                for key in row_original.keys() not in sub_row.keys():
                    # si la columna ya no existe en row la puestamos
                    sub_row[key] = row_original[key]
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-da20e669a107> in <module>
      4             qid = str(row['QID']).split("_")
      5             # get the sub dataframe where the first part of the QID is the same with qid
----> 6             sub_df = df.loc[df['QID'].split("_")[0] == qid[0]] # df['QID'].split("_")[0], to get the qgrid rows
      7             # for each question in sub_df adapt their qid with row_original qid respecting "_" and provide the row values
      8             for sub_row in sub_df.iterrows():

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5272             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5273                 return self[name]
-> 5274             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5275 
   5276     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'
```

## Actualizacion

Tambien intenté la respuesta de ansev:

```
#Seleccionamos la columnas de df_original a unir
#tomamos todas las que no estan en df y adicionalmente Questions y QID
cols_original_merge = ['Questions', 'QID'] + [col for col in df_original 
                                              if col not in df.columns]

#creamos una copia de df_orginal seleccionando solo las columnas 
#de cols_original_merge.
#Hacemos la fusión en función de Questions.
df = df.merge(df_original[cols_original_merge], on = 'Questions', how='left')

# Se crean dos columnas QID: QID_X y QID_Y
# QID_x contiene los valores anteriores de QID
# QID_y contiene los valores nuevos de QID

# Escribimos los valores faltantes de QID_y con los valores de QID_x
# Eliminamos QID_x
# Renombramos QID_y a QID

df = (df.assign(QID_y = df['QID_y'].fillna(df['QID_x']))
        .drop('QID_x', axis=1)
        .rename({'QID_y' : 'QID'}, axis = 1)
     )
```

Esta es praticamente perfecto pero ciertos numeros aparecen varias veces y otras como los alfanumericos:

```
>>>df.head()
    QID     Questions   QType   Answer0     Answer1     Answer2     Answer3     Answer4     Answer5     Answer6     ...     10f     11a     11b     11c     11d     11e     Sum     Comment     Beyond repair   Not scrapped well
0   0   How do you feel about your next vacation after...   Checkboxes  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1   0   When do you think your next vacation can start?     Multiple Choice     In next 3 months    In next 6 months    In next 1 year  Only once COVID-19 is under control     Only once COVID-19 vaccine is developed     NaN     NaN     ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN     2.0     google forum seems broken at points needs to b...   NaN     NaN
2   1   What are your preferences regarding medical tr...   Likert Scale    Doctor's availability in hotel  Ventilator availability in hotel    Tie-ups with nearby hospitals   Availability of medical rooms with primary fir...   NaN     NaN     NaN     ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     7.0     NaN     1.0     NaN
3   2   What is your preferences of complementary brea...   Multiple Choice     Buffet breakfast with social distancing     Buffet breakfast replaced with Ala-carte with ...   Breakfast to be delivered in room with limited...   Packaged breakfast only     NaN     NaN     NaN     ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
4   2   What is your preference for a in-hotel grocery...   Multiple Choice     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     3.0     This could be replaced with a binary question   NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Me parece que no es posible plantear una solución genérica, no hay datos para relacionar de forma consistente ambas tablas, o falta una definición de tu parte. Te pongo un ejemplo: En el `df` original el `QUID=23` la pregunta es `Gender` , pero no es el único `Gender` de este `df`, hay 3 o 4 más que imagino son de otras preguntas, ¿Como se supone que se pueda relacionar por medio de la pregunta si está se repite?

Comment: Gracias @PatricioMoracho por tu comentario, creo que tienes razón. A menos que 1. utilice el número máximo de columnas para unir las dos tablas de forma coherente, o que falte una definición de su parte. O 2. adaptar [la respuesta a la pregunta que me permitió crear df a partir de df_original](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/377209/2633) para que no perdamos esos QIDs

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo unir DataFrames en Pandas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/403245/c%c3%b3mo-unir-dataframes-en-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para este tipo de tareas utlizamos [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandasdocs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Creo que simplemente podemos hacer:

```
#Seleccionamos la columnas de df_original a unir
#tomamos todas las que no estan en df y adicionalmente Questions y QID
cols_original_merge = ['Questions', 'QID'] + [col for col in df_original 
                                              if col not in df.columns]

#creamos una copia de df_orginal seleccionando solo las columnas 
#de cols_original_merge.
#Hacemos la fusión en función de Questions.
df = df.merge(df_original[cols_original_merge], on='Questions', how='left')

# Se crean dos columnas QID: QID_X y QID_Y
# QID_x contiene los valores anteriores de QID
# QID_y contiene los valores nuevos de QID

# Escribimos los valores faltantes de QID_y con los valores de QID_x
# Eliminamos QID_x
# Renombramos QID_y a QID

df = (df.assign(QID_y = df['QID_y'].fillna(df['QID_x']))
        .drop('QID_x', axis=1)
        .rename({'QID_y' : 'QID'}, axis=1)
     )
```

- utilizamos `left` para conservar las filas de df donde Questions no coincide con `df_original` (para ninguna combinación de filas).
- Tenga en cuenta que puede resultar muy costoso computacionalmente utilizar `.iterrows()` aquí. Para hacer este tipo de cosas tenemos merge, join etc. Le recomiendo que consulte [`esta excelente pregunta (pandas merging 101)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) e incluso la estudie.

No he ejecutado el código para ver si funciona porque tengo dudas acerca del ejemplo y creo que deberia ser simplificado, de todas formas compruebelo y comente cualquier duda.

Answer (score 0):

Me costo entender bastante el patrón que relaciona ambas tablas, entiendo que es algo así:

```
╔══════════════════╦══════════════════╦══════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Pregunta Tabla A ║ Pregunta Tabla B ║ Detalle                              ║
╠══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════╣
║ AA               ║                  ║ Preguntas en A que no existen en B   ║
╠══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════╣
║ BA               ║ BA               ║ Preguntas en A que existen en B      ║
╠══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════╣
║ CD               ║ CD               ║ Caso anterior pero pregunta padre    ║
╠══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════╣
║ CD               ║ CD_1             ║ B que no existen en A (subpreguntas) ║
╠══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════╣
║ CD               ║ CD_2             ║ B que no existen en A (subpreguntas) ║
╠══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════╣
║ DR               ║ DR               ║ Preguntas en A y B pero repetidas    ║
╚══════════════════╩══════════════════╩══════════════════════════════════════╝
```

La tabla A son las preguntas Originales. Vemos más en detalle cada caso:

- **Preguntas en A que no existen en B**: Hay varas líneas o preguntas que no existen en la tabla B, parecen ser caso particulares dónde además estas no tienen un a `URL` por lo que son fáciles de identificar. Por ejemplo `Thinking about this callendar year, what of the following applies to you?`
- **Preguntas en A que existen en B**, pero sin repeticiones (relación 1=1) este es el caso ideal, ya que simplemente podríamos relacionar ambas tablas, por medio de algún tipo de `join` basándonos en `Questions` como clave de la relación y usando [`merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). Por ejemplo `What are your preferences regarding medical treatment policy (with additional cost)?`
- **Pregunta en B que no existen en A (subpreguntas)**, en este caso hay que encontrar la relación con la pregunta "padre" y "expandir" los resultados con todas las subpreguntas. Ejemplo `What are new offers you are most interested in?`. Es un caso dónde no tendremos un `QID` en A pero hay que trasladar igualmente las filas de B con el `QID_<nro>`.
- **Preguntas en A y B pero repetidas** este podría ser como el caso 2, salvo por el hecho que la `Questions` es un texto que se repite en varias encuestas, por ejemplo el término `Gender` como texto aparece unas 17 veces. Esto es una complicación importante para resolverlo todo mediante [`merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), y hay que atacarlo de otra forma

Yo creo que deberías replantear el proceso ya que en la práctica tranquilamente se podría decir que no hay forma de relacionar univocamente todas las filas de A con las de B. No al menos desde una visón relacional clásica.

¿Esto significa que no se pueden relacionar ambas tablas? No, pero tenemos que intentar una solución bastante más compleja y que puede o no funcionar del todo.

Los casos 1, 2, y 3 son relativamente sencillos de resolver, el 4 es el que necesita un poco más de trabajo, vamos a asumir para este caso, un orden secuencial de las preguntas que se repiten, de forma tal que los 17 `Gender` de A serán relacionados a los 17 `Gender` de B con el mismo orden (siempre que en ambas tablas existan la misma cantidad de filas).

La idea final sería llegar a una tabla que pueda funcionar de pivote, luego, para unir cada fila. La idea es que tenga:

- `Questions`: El texto de la pregunta
- `QID_A`: El `QID` en en el df original (salvo en el caso de las subpreguntas, dónde no existe este dato en B)
- `QID_B`: El `QID` en el df B, salvo en el caso de las preguntas que no existen en B, este en la mayoría de los casos representa el nuevo `QID` que buscas.
- `QUID_PADRE`: En el caso de las subpreguntas, para control, será el `QID` de la pregunta "padre".

Esta sería más o menos la idea:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

df1 = pd.read_csv('~/Descargas/QuestionBank.csv', low_memory=False)
df2 = pd.read_csv('~/Descargas/QuestionBank_31072020_1220.csv', low_memory=False)

A = df1[ ['Questions', 'QID', 'URL']].astype(str)
B = df2[['Questions', 'QID']].astype(str)
A['Questions'] = A['Questions'].str.strip()
B['Questions'] = B['Questions'].str.strip()

# Dividimos el QID de las subpreguntas en QID y número de subpregunta
B[['QID_B','nr']] = pd.DataFrame(B.QID.str.split('_',1).tolist(),columns = ['QID_B','nr'])

 # 1. Preguntas en A que no están en B
A1 = A[~A.Questions.isin(B.Questions)].dropna()
A1 = A1[["Questions", "QID"]]
A1.columns = ["Questions", "QID_A"]
A1["QID_B"] = pd.NA
A1["QID_PADRE"] = pd.NA

# 2. Preguntas en A que están en B y no se repiten
A2 = A[A.Questions.isin(B.Questions)].dropna().groupby('Questions').filter(lambda x: len(x) == 1)
A2 = A2.merge(B, on = 'Questions', how='inner')[["Questions", "QID_x", "QID_y"]]
A2["QID_PADRE"] = pd.NA
A2.columns = ["Questions", "QID_A", "QID_B", "QID_PADRE"]

# 3. Preguntas en A que están en B y no se repiten y tienen subpreguntas
A3 = A2.merge(B[B["QID"].str.contains("_")], on = 'QID_B', how='inner')[["Questions_y", "QID_A", "QID_B", "QID"]]
A3["QID_A"] = pd.NA
A3 = A3[["Questions_y", "QID_A", "QID", "QID_B"]]
A3.columns = ["Questions", "QID_A", "QID_B", "QID_PADRE"]

# 4. Preguntas que se repiten las relacionamos si se puede de manera secuencial
A4 = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=A3.columns)
TMP = A[A.Questions.isin(B.Questions)].dropna().groupby('Questions').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
batches = []
for _, r in TMP.iterrows():
    q = r.Questions

    a = A[A.Questions == q].reset_index()
    b = B[B.Questions == q].reset_index()

    rows_a, rows_b = a.shape[0], b.shape[0]
    if rows_a == rows_b:
        c = pd.merge(a, b, left_index=True, right_index=True)[["Questions_x", "QID_x", "QID_y"]]
        c["QID_PADRE"] = pd.NA
        c.columns = ["Questions", "QID_A", "QID_B", "QID_PADRE"]
        batches.append(c)

A4 = pd.concat(batches)

# Unimos los tres lotes
FINAL = pd.concat([A1, A2, A3, A4])

print(FINAL)
```

La salida de `FINAL`:

```
                                             Questions QID_A QID_B QID_PADRE
1    Thinking about this callendar year, what of th...    0R  <NA>      <NA>
6    What of the following measures, would make you...    5R  <NA>      <NA>
274  In the last two years have you stayed in any o...  267R  <NA>      <NA>
276  In the last two years how often have you staye...  268R  <NA>      <NA>
278  If you stay at ABC Hotels which type of room d...  269R  <NA>      <NA>
..                                                 ...   ...   ...       ...
6                                     How old are you?  1715  1628      <NA>
7                                     How old are you?  1895  1829      <NA>
8                                     How old are you?  2551  2443      <NA>
0                     How do you usually book a hotel?  2288  2206      <NA>
1                     How do you usually book a hotel?  2613  2509      <NA>

[4507 rows x 4 columns]
```

El `QID_B` en la mayoría de los casos (Salvo en las preguntas de A que no existen en B) es lo que deberíamos considerar como nuevo `QID`.

Con esta tabla "pivote" tranquilamente podrías unir las columnas de los dos `df` con los que arrancamos:

```
UNION = FINAL.merge(df1.dropna(subset=['QID']), how="left", left_on="QID_A", right_on="QID")
UNION = UNION.merge(df2.dropna(subset=['QID']), how="left", left_on="QID_B", right_on="QID")
```

Ten en cuenta que `UNION` vas a tener todas las columnas de A y de B, las columas que se repiten, tendrán un sufijo `_x` e `_y` respectivamente, si quieres que queden algunas solas en particular, simplemente agrégalas en la selección final.

Finalmente ¿Esto resuelve todos los casos?, al menos los indicados más arriba Sí, deberías analizar claro, si los casos que mencionados son todos los posibles.